# In Laravel api.php file found code Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) ... what purpose it's have?

Tags: php, laravel

In fresh installed Laravel api.php file found code

```
   Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
      return $request->user();
    });
```

What purpose does it have ?

I am using GET request to URL `my-application/user`,  no any Response, is something wrong ?

Can I delete that code ?

Comment: its just an example. Sure you should be able to delete without any issue. BTW your url should be /api/user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`your-url/user` url is protected by auth:api `middleware`

you have to pass token with http [request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests) to access this.

in your current route it will return authenticated user model data

for more read the document from [laravel passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport)

Answer (score 1):

> What purpose does it have ?

It is a sample route. It is to show, how to apply the authentication layer on `api` routes. And, retrieve the authenticated user.

> I am using GET request to URL my-application/user, no any Response, is something wrong ?

You need to consider two thing here.

1. All api routes are prefixed with `/api/`. So, the URL should be `my-application/api/user`

   https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/2a483bbf60566cab6fbd0340fb3877fc09889bc3/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L68
2. Since `auth:api` middleware is applied, it expect a token to be presented.

If you remove the `auth:api` middleware and prefix with `api`, you could see a response.

> Can I delete that code ?

Yes, you can delete.